# Fatal error: Class 'Linksture_Faqs_Helper_Data' not found in public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento-1.9, error, admin-panel

So I installed an add on for a FAQ template, but encountered a problem while doing so. It didn't install correctly, so I attempted to just remove all the files. In doing so, I was hit with this error when trying to access my admin control panel and am completely unable to access anything in it now because of this error.

I'm assuming there's a database value that's wrong, but am unsure where to look and what to change it to.  Any help would be great to avoid having to upload a back up.

Answer (score 3):

The ***faq Extension does not contain Helper class***, that reason ***it showing error.***

If  your Faq module *nameSpace*  `SpaceLinksture` and Name is  `Faqs`.

And assume that it located at **`app/code/community or local/SpaceLinksture/Faq`**

On it config.xml `(`**which located at app/code/community or local/SpaceLinksture/Faq /etc**`)` you need to define helper class 
by

...

> ```
> <global>
> .... <!-- add the helper class -->
>   <helpers>
>       <faqs>
>       <class>Linksture_Faqs_Helper</class>
>       </faq>
>   </helpers>
> ....
> </global>
> ```

then  add helper class Data.php  at **`app/code/community or local/SpaceLinksture/Faq/Helper`**

> ```
> <?php 
> class Linksture_Faqs_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
> }
> ```

It will resolve your issue

Comment: Well the problem is that I had removed all the files related to the add on, so there's no directory for it anymore. Would I be better off reinstalling it and adding the helper class manually?

Comment: yes.. you need to add the helper class

Comment: Okay, so `config.xml` currently inside `app/code/local/Linksture/Faqs/etc` contains the helper class already.

Comment: Sorry, and the Data.php contains
`class Linksture_Faqs_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data`

Comment: here faqs is not properly end. its end with </faqs> in config.xml file.

Comment: @taskle,Please share  your code

Comment: @AmitBera Since I couldn't figure out the issue, I had to restore back to an earlier day before installing the add on. The error was gone, and I reinstalled with no problems. So unfortunately I still don't know what the actual problem was.